# Can I reference an app under an alternative name on the Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

I just published an app named `Air2G²` on the Play Store and App Store.

I know most people will search for `air2g2` instead, with an actual "2" as the last character, so I added that alternative writing into the short and long descriptions.

On the App Store the app is found when looking for `air2g2` but not on the Play Store, how can I have my app to be found on the Play Store?

Comment: just rename the app to air2g2

Comment: @Style-7 the project's name is `Air2G²` that's how my client has deposited it and displays it so he really wants the app's name to be displayed like that on the Play Store :/

Comment: app name and name in the Google Play is not the same